# Select relateditemnumber from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like

```
<filters>
  <ritem relateditemnumber="8901037" />
  <ritem relateditemnumber="8901038" />
  <ritem relateditemnumber="8901039" />
  <ritem relateditemnumber="8901040" />
</filters>
```

iwant to get the first relateditemnumber form this xml using xslt.
I tried like

```
<xsl:value-of select="$prid/relateditemnumber"/>
```

but is not getting.anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/filters/ritem/@relateditemnumber"/>
```

You can write this in short notation:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//@relateditemnumber"/>
```

### XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/filters/ritem/@relateditemnumber"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```